# split ArrayList into given number of sub-ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

There is an Arraylist which has size 14 and I have to divide it into 6 sub-arraylists.

```
List<Integer> list;
list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14));
```

For example like below :

14/6 = 2.333

Now when I'll take ceil value 3 then only 5 sub-arraylist will be created and when I'll take floor value i.e. 2 then 7 sub-arraylist will be created **but I need 6**.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: You can use subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)

Comment: If you want exactly 6 sub list then some of your sublists must have different number of elements in it.

Comment: Output should come like this:
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8]
[9,10]
[11,12]
[13,14]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, might have some issues, but can be tweaked

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                11, 12, 13, 14));
        int number = 6;
        int factor = list.size() / number;

        int fromIndex = 0;
        int toIndex = factor;

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            if (i < number - 1) {
                System.out.println(list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
                fromIndex = toIndex;
                toIndex = fromIndex + factor;
            } else {
                System.out.println(list.subList(fromIndex, list.size()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Input - `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13, 14`

Output

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Input - `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13`

Output

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
[11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Output should be like this:
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8]
[9,10]
[11,12]
[13,14]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a "divide and conquer" method, use a recursive call to split the arrays in half until you get the number of arrays you need. Of course if you want an odd number of arrays, that would mean that you have one that is double the size of the rest.

Another solution would be to create 6 empty lists and just add an item to each while removing from the original until the original list is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14));
    int noofsublist = 6;   //no of subparts
    int chopsize = Math.floor(arrayList.size()/noofsublist);

    for (int start = 0; start < arrayList.size(); start += chopsize) {
        int end = Math.min(start + chopsize, arrayList.size());
        List<String> sublist = arrayList.subList(start, end);
        System.out.println(sublist);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a homework problem, but if it was a real-life scenario, I'd use Guava's [`Lists.partition()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)) method:

```
List<List<Integer>> partitions = Lists.partition(yourList, n);
```

Where `n` is the maximum size of your sub list. A naive formula for n is `yourList.size() / desiredNumberOfSubLists() + 1`

In your case it would be `14 / 6 + 1 = 3`, but unfortunately that creates 5 sub lists, not 6.

So here's a custom method that splits into n partitions, distributing the elements to the individual lists as fair as possible:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> partitionIntoNLists(final List<T> list, final int n) {
    final List<List<T>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(n);
    final int[] partitionSizes = new int[n];
    int offset = 0;

    // round robin to distribute partition sizes
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        partitionSizes[offset++]++;
        if (offset == n) {
            offset = 0;
        }
    }

    offset = 0;
    for (final int partitionSize : partitionSizes) {
        listOfLists.add(list.subList(offset, offset + partitionSize));
        offset += partitionSize;
    }

    return listOfLists;
}
```

Test code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);
    for (List<Integer> integers : partitionIntoNLists(list, 6)) {
        System.out.println(integers);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
[11, 12]
[13, 14]
```

Comment: If you partition 14 in partitions of 3, you will get 5 partitions, not 6.

Comment: @KenGeis true. There is no easy way to split into 6 Lists in a generic way

Comment: If by "easy" you mean a call to a popular library, then I'd agree. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @KenGeis your answer does not return the lists in the exact way the OP specified them (3 elements in the first lists only). My updated solution does

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14));
int parts = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    List<String> part = list.subList(i * list.size() / parts,
                                     (i + 1) * list.size() / parts);
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

outputs

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
[8, 9]
[10, 11]
[12, 13, 14]
```